# Updating links to files with vba in Publisher

Tags: vba, ms-publisher

How can I automate the process of updating links to OLEObjects in Publisher with a macro? I have found some discussion of how to do this (mostly in PowerPoint), and I am experiencing a couple of issues when trying to apply this to a 2010 Publisher document.

First, when I display the .LinkFormat.SourceFullName in a message box, none of the references to the Excel worksheet or object appear as they do in the dialogue box when I edit links to files through the menu options.

Second, when I attempt to simply change the file name that appears as the .SourceFullName, I receive a compile error message that says I can't assign to a read-only property.

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

When I apply the following code, I get the compile error when trying to assign the new link name. If I comment out the .SourceFullName = newlinkname line, I get message boxes that tell me I have Edit and Open ObjectVerbs available, and the linkname that is displayed only includes "C:\Desktop\Projects\old.xlsx." It does not show the worksheet and chart references that I see linked to the object when I use the Edit Links to Files command through the ribbon. There, the dialogue box actually shows:

old.xlsx!H_A_CurrStat_byYrDxBar![old.xlsx]H_A_CurrStat_byYrDxBar Chart 1

I want to use a macro to change the source name from old.xlsx to new.xlsx and then update the linked objects.

```
Option Explicit

Sub links()

Dim linkname As String
Dim newlinkname As String
Dim shpShape As Shape
Dim intCount As Integer

newlinkname = "C:\Desktop\Projects\new.xlsx"

    For Each shpShape In ActiveDocument.Pages(1).Shapes
       shpShape.OLEFormat.Activate

               With shpShape.OLEFormat
                    For intCount = 1 To .ObjectVerbs.count
                     MsgBox .ObjectVerbs(intCount)
                    Next
                End With

            With shpShape.LinkFormat
                linkname = .SourceFullName
                '.SourceFullName = newlinkname
                MsgBox linkname
            End With

       shpShape.LinkFormat.Update
    Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff940537.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

This code for activating all objects might help:

```
    Sub ActivateOLEObjects() 
            Dim shpShape As Shape 

            For Each shpShape In ActiveDocument.Pages(1).Shapes 
                    If shpShape.Type = pbLinkedOLEObject Then 
                            shpShape.OLEFormat.Activate 
                    End If 
            Next 
    End Sub
```

Or perhaps even better, this example code for updating links:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff939544.aspx

```
    Sub FindOLEObjects() 
            Dim shpShape As Shape 

            For Each shpShape In ActiveDocument.Pages(1).Shapes 
                    If shpShape.Type = pbLinkedOLEObject Then 
                            shpShape.LinkFormat.Update 
                    End If 
            Next shpShape 
    End Sub
```

If neither helps, please provide some more info, like an example file or your current code